# Вставить *insert* массив в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Array ( 
[success] => 1 
[data] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [firm_id] => 10 
        [region_name] => CITY1
        [district_name] => г. CITY1 
        [branch_id] => 10A 
        [branch_name] => Головной офис 
        [branch_f_name] => Головной офис 
        [branch_addr] => street 99 
        [latitude] => 1.23119354248 
        [longitude] => 2.961814880371 
        [arh] => 0 
        [up_date] => 29.10.2018 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [firm_id] => 11 
        [region_name] => CITY2 
        [district_name] => г. CITY2 
        [branch_id] => 11F 
        [branch_name] => 2 OFFICE 
        [branch_f_name] => Отделение OFFICE 
        [branch_addr] => Street 31 
        [latitude] => 4.165832519531 
        [longitude] => 5.999877929688 
        [arh] => 0 
        [up_date] => 29.10.2018 
    )
```

как такой массив Insert в mysql ?
Задача такова, что мне нужно данные пропарсить в БД, а как это сделать не соображаю, так как с такой задачей не сталкивался.

Comment: Написать текст запроса, подставить в него данные, выполнить запрос столько раз сколько требуется.

Comment: создать таблицу БД с соответствующей структурой для начала

Comment: @teran этак мы до разворачивания сервера дойдем.

Comment: @u_mulder сразу с закупки комплектующих начинать надо =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а че далеко идти та давайте уже микроконтроллеры варить.

Comment: @DDdd тогда нам надо закупить оборудование для производства МК, ой нет... нам надо произвести оборудование для производства...... =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков давайте лучше научимся камень об камень бить, что бы искры получить для огня ) а там видно в будущем надеюсь найдут ответ )))